# How does static variable in Java work?

Tags: java

When the below code is executed

```
class Foo {

    static int size = 7;

    static void changeIt(int size) {
        size = size + 200;
        System.out.println("size in changeIt is " + size);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("size = " + size);
        changeIt(size);
        System.out.println("size after changeIt is " + size);
    }
}
```

the answer will be

```
size = 7
size in changeIt is 207
size after changeIt is 7
```

The answer which I expected was

```
size  after changeIt is 207
```

Why the values of static variable is differing in the `changeIt` method and the `main` method ?

Comment: You should read about variable shadowing and scope.

Comment: This has nothing to do with static variables. The `size` argument in `changeIt` is "hiding" the static field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the values of static variable is differing in the changeIt method and the main method ?

The values are different because you didn't change the `static` variable `size`, you changed the local variable `size`. Change the code to:

```
static void changeIt() {
    size = size + 200;
    System.out.println("size in changeIt is " + size);
}
```

Or, if you want to use an argument with the same name, you can specify that you are using the `static` class variable by qualifying it with the class name:

```
static void changeIt(int size) {
    Foo.size = size;
    System.out.println("size in changeIt is " + Foo.size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change `size = size + 200` to

```
Foo.size = size + 200;
```

size is local in your method, then you change the variable that you want.

The problem is that the parameter name `size` is equal to name of the static field `size` so when you point it in that method compiler considers the local variable.

Comment: Would probably be better as Foo.size

Answer (score 1):

Java and many other languages do what is called `local variable shadowing`. That means the local variable `size` will "cover up" the class-level variable `size`.

You can work around this by either using `this.size`, or removing the `size` parameter from your method signature.

If you want more details on Java specifically, you can consult the [JLS 6.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1).

Answer (score 1):

Your method:

```
static void changeIt(int size) 
{
    size = size + 200;
    System.out.println("size in changeIt is " + size);
}
```

Does not change your internal static member variable. It takes an integer and adds 200 to it. If you just want this method to add 200 to your static member variable your function should look like this:

```
static void changeIt() 
{
    size = size + 200;
    System.out.println("size in changeIt is " + size);
}
```

To learn more about static variables, look here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the parameter name 'size' which is same as the static variable.
When you type

```
size = size + 1;
```

you change the value of local variable. Use

```
ClassName.size += 1;
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
 static void changeIt(int size) {
 size = size + 200;
 System.out.println("size in changeIt is " + size);
  }
```

Assume that you replace "size" with "x". Then you can simply understand the answer you get is correct. 
Just like that "size" in the changeIt() method does not even compare with the static "size". Read bit more stuff about scope of variables.